# Where has prevu gone in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04

Prevu is probably my #1 reason to use Ubuntu over Debian/testing. Just upgraded my system to 12.04/x64, and prevu is gone. What happened? Where did it go? How do I get it back? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick search shows that it's been removed as "un-maintained, buggy, and superseded by backportpackage from ubuntu-dev-tools": https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/prevu/+bug/948191

See if backportpackage from ubuntu-dev-tools suits your needs

Comment: Thanks for finding the rationale. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get backportpackage to actually do what prevu used to do: ie, grab source, make a build chroot, pull in build deps, build a package, and make it available locally for install.